# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIBackgroundTaskInfo setStoreObserver:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282b20780'

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, mkstorekit

In the process of updating some older code, and whilst the code launches, it crashes immediately upon launch. I am using XCode 10, previously this would have worked fine in XCode 7/8

This line in `AppController.mm`

`[[MKStoreManager sharedManager] requestProductData];`

That line brings you to

```
MKStoreManager.m

- (void) requestProductData
{
    SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: 
                                 [NSSet setWithObjects: /*featureAllLevels, */ foodIAP, vanityIAP, dressIAP, iceIAP, allIAP, nil]]; // add any other product here
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}
```

The error itself is

`objc[680]: MKStoreManager object 0x281ecd020 overreleased while already deallocating; break on objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug
2019-09-19 12:15:18.342037+0100 PoolParty[680:66967] -[_UIBackgroundTaskInfo setStoreObserver:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281ecd020
2019-09-19 12:15:18.342502+0100 PoolParty[680:66967] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIBackgroundTaskInfo setStoreObserver:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281ecd020'`

Struggling to figure out this, if anyone could assist I would appreciate!